# ggplot legend options will not be adopted in ggplotly in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I created a plot with ggplot2 and want to publish it in my Shiny App with plottly. Unfortunately the position of the legend is not adopted. Furthermore a 1 is added to every entry in the legend and the caption of the Plot disappears.

Part of my Plot

```
plot = ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = pi_plot, aes(x = as.Date(Month), y = value, fill = Domain), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(data = pi_fc_ly_plot, aes(x = as.Date(Month), y = value, group = PI, colour = PI), size = 0.75) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "Traffic",
       subtitle = "Visits", 
       y = "Pageviews", 
       x = "Month", 
       caption = "Source: Google Analytics") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%B"), 
               date_breaks = "month",
               expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Call the Plot in the App

```
ggplotly(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar some time ago. I specified my legend position as part of my 
ggplotly function call instead of my ggplot function call. You could try to amend your code as follows and see if it works

```
plot = ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = pi_plot, aes(x = as.Date(Month), y = value, fill = Domain), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(data = pi_fc_ly_plot, aes(x = as.Date(Month), y = value, group = PI, colour = PI), size = 0.75) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "Traffic",
       subtitle = "Visits", 
       y = "Pageviews", 
       x = "Month", 
       caption = "Source: Google Analytics") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%B"), 
               date_breaks = "month",
               expand = c(0, 0))

 ggplotly(plot) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y=-0.5))
```

I don't know about the source of your caption issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could solve the problem with the position.